# static typed object enumerable collection declaration

Tags: c#, class, static, declaration

I have several editor. Each editor have specificities, for exemple a specific field type in database or is editable or no.

So i need a collection of editor type with name and properties. I need to be able to populate a combobox with the collection

How can i declare each type and have a type list?

i try this

```
public enum TemplateType
{TextBox,ColorPicker};

    public class TabloidBaseControl
{
    public static DbType DefaultFieldType { get { return DbType.String; } }
    public static int? DefaultFieldLength { get { return 20; } }
    public static int? DefaultFieldDecimal { get { return null; } }
}

public class TCColorPicker:TabloidBaseControl
{
    public new static int? DefaultFieldLength = 7;
}

public class TCTextBox: TabloidBaseControl
{
    public new static int? DefaultFieldLength = 20;
}

    public static Dictionary<TemplateType, TabloidBaseControl> TabloidControlList = new Dictionary<TemplateType, TabloidBaseControl> {
        {TemplateType.TextBox,new TCTextBox()},
        {TemplateType.ColorPicker,new TCColorPicker() }

    };
```

is it the right way?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: Yes this is my code... But the exemple of vehicle is not a good idea i remove it

Comment: Okay, well, what's wrong with the code you've got? What does it not do that you want to do? In other words, this question is still very vague. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: At first sorry for my english. I have a lot of editor each one have same properties for exemple a field type needed in database. I need to have a list of this editor to populate in combobox and from the selected value find the database field type.

Comment: I get that part, but I don't understand why this code doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Because my dictionary return an instance of type and static properties can't be accessed. if i remove static it work but i always get tabloidbasecontrol value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing the class inheritance correctly. Use virtual properties on the base class, and override the appropriate ones in the derived classes, like so:

```
public enum TemplateType
{TextBox,ColorPicker};

public class TabloidBaseControl
{
  public virtual DbType DefaultFieldType
  {
    get { return DbType.String; }
  }

  public virtual int? DefaultFieldLength
  {
    get { return 20; }
  }

  public virtual int? DefaultFieldDecimal
  {
    get { return null; }
  }
}

public class TCColorPicker : TabloidBaseControl
{
  public override int? DefaultFieldLength
  {
    get { return 7; }
  }
}

public class TCTextBox : TabloidBaseControl
{
  public override int? DefaultFieldLength
  {
    get { return 20; }
  }
}
```

And yes, your dictionary will always return the object as an instance of the base class, since that is how it is defined. However, the runtime type of the object will be whichever derived class you added, so the proper value will be returned from the property accessor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i Will try your solution. Is there a way using static object?

Comment: No, why would you want to use static properties anyway?

Comment: I would like to use object as type With no  need to instantiate

Comment: Without instantiation, there is no inheritance. Without inheritance, there is no polymorphism.

Comment: If i do not use base class is there a way to build a collection

Comment: No, there isn't. Not the way you apparently want to use it.

Comment: Not the way you apparently use?